# How to trigger GITLAB pipeline from testrail

Tags: testing, automation, architecture, gitlab, testrail

Currently we are using Testrail and Gitlab pipeline.
I want to trigger gitlab pipeline from testrail itself. Please let me know

I am still searching for it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced the same need. And I've solved it in that way:

- Create a trigger for the pipeline in GitLab ([see the instruction](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/index.html))
- Add a UI script to TestRail (Administration -> Customizations -> UI scripts), which would add a button to trigger the pipeline by clicking on it (the script is based on the info found [here](https://github.com/gurock/testrail-custom/tree/master/user-submitted/ui-scripts) and [here](https://support.testrail.com/hc/en-us/articles/7344009893908-UI-scripts-introduction#writing-ui-scripts-0-0))

```js
name: Trigger GitLab Pipeline
description: Triggers a GitLab pipeline
author:
version: 1.0
includes: ^runs
excludes: 

js:
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create the button
    var button = $('<div class="toolbar content-header-toolbar"><a class="toolbar-button toolbar-button-last toolbar-button-first content-header-button button-start" href="javascript:void(0)">Start Tests</a></div>');
    
    // Add the button to the TestRail page
    $("#content-header .content-header-inner").prepend(button);

    // Bind the click event to trigger the GitLab pipeline
    $("a", button).click(function() {
 
        // Send the request to trigger the GitLab pipeline
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/yourProjectId/trigger/pipeline?token=yourPipelineToken&ref=yourBranch',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function() {
                // Pipeline triggered successfully
                alert('GitLab pipeline triggered successfully.');
            },
            error: function() {
                // Handle errors
                alert('Failed to trigger GitLab pipeline.');
            },
        });
    });
});
```

- Enable remote access to TestRail (Administration -> Site Settings -> Security tab -> scroll down to "CSP - Allow access TestRail to remote addresses" -> enable checkbox and write down your GitLab host)

That'll do. Now button to trigger the pipeline should be displayed in the Test Runs & Results section like that
[Start Tests button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKNcr.png)